# How to get current category name by current category url in observer magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to get category name by current url in the observer. I have tried most common code but not working, so I am trying to get category name or id by current url.
For example, current url is : http://example.php/food.html. 
Here I want category id by this url.

I have tried this in my observer :

```
namespace Mymodule\Event\Observer\Logger;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class GlobalLogger implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
        echo $category->getId();
        echo $category->getName();
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea for that, please?

Comment: Its working for me fine in category page where are you checking this code, in which page?

Comment: can u share your observer code?

Comment: i have updated my code, kindly please check, i am using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check first whether current request is from category page and if from category then you need to call below code,

```
namespace Mymodule\Event\Observer\Logger;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
class GlobalLogger implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $registry;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        if($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'category'){ 
            $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');//get current category
            echo $category->getId();
            echo $category->getName();
        }
     }
 }
```

Remove var and generated folder from root and check again.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Comment: i have removed var and generated folder, and used above, but not responding. i have checked current request is catalog_category_view of action name

Comment: can we get current category in this action "catalog_category_view"

Comment: i havent try with that might be getting using those action

Answer (score 2):

**Try below code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mymodule\Event\Observer\Logger;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;   

/**
 * Class GlobalLogger
 */
class GlobalLogger implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    */

    protected $registry;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->request      = $request;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Set new customer group to all his quotes
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        if($category) {
          echo $category->getName();
          die;
        }
    }
}
```

After run below compiler command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as i apply this then getting blank screen. i have updated my code, kindly please check, i am using this.

Comment: on which event your code put. can give your event?

Comment: I am using "predispatch event".

Comment: Update ans pls check and let me know any issue

Comment: i have used above code and run this command, i think code is not coming in this code if($category) {
          echo $category->getName();
          die;
        }