# Magento 2.4.2: How to find out if it is category page in the observer class?

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, no-index

My objective is to set a specific category to `NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW` in an observer class. Below is my event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="layout_load_before">

        <observer name="add_robot_page" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Noindexfollow" />

    </event>    

</config>
```

Here is the observer class where I need to first find out if it is the category page and if so, find out if it contains the string "part" in the title and set it to noindex and nofollow here.

```
<?php
  
namespace Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SetRobotsMetaTag implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $registry;
    protected $layoutFactory;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger)

    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $this->logger->debug("Observer is alert");
        if ($this->request->getActionName() == 'category') { 
            $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
            $categoryName = $category->getName();
            if (stripos($categoryName, 'part') !== false) { 
                $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/207753/46039

$catname = $category->getName();
if(strpos('part', $catname) !== false){
{
set here.
}

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
class Noindexfollow implements ObserverInterface

{

    protected $request;
    protected $registry;
    protected $layoutFactory;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,

        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory)

    {

            $this->registry = $registry;
            $this->request = $request;

            $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;

    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)

    {

        if($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'category'){ 

            $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
            $categoryName = $category->getName();
            if(strpos('part', categoryName) !== false){ 

            $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');

            } 
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I get this message from Intelephense: Method 'Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Observer\Noindexfollow::execute()' is not compatible with method 'Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute()'.intelephense(1038)

Comment: I am not sure but Magento have no any Perfectmakeupmirrors related module.

might be it is your third party module.

Comment: add try cache block in observer and check it.

Comment: Yes, it is my custom module only. I already got 2 Observer classes in created nearly 3 years ago.

Comment: S.P< the observer class is not getting invoked as verified with use of logger.

Comment: check your custom module with observer disable,

Or put same code in Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Observer\Noindexfollow there.